# Exception when clearing the all controls in a form

Tags: c#, winforms, exception

I have some textboxes in my form. I wrote the code on leave event to add 0.00 automatically. I wrote the code to add two textboxes value to the third one as

```
try
{
    decimal netVal = 0;
    decimal.TryParse(txtNetValue.Text, out netVal);
    decimal disc2 = 0;
    decimal.TryParse(txtDisc2.Text, out disc2);
    decimal tax1 = 0;
    decimal.TryParse(txtTax1.Text, out tax1);

    decimal tax = netVal - disc2;
    string strtax = ((tax / 100) * tax1).ToString();
    txtTax2.Text = strtax.Substring(0, strtax.IndexOf(".") + 3);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

In this case when I click the new button to clear all the controls I am getting an exception as `Index and length must refer to a location within the string. Parameter name: length`.

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is here:

```
strtax.Substring(0, strtax.IndexOf(".") + 3);
```

I don't believe that [Substring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs.aspx) does what you think it does. The arguments are not "startIndex" and "endIndex" (Beginning and End), they are "startIndex" and "Length" (Beginning and *length of substring*). Most likely, this confusion is causing you to attempt to get a substring that is larger than the size of the string.

For example, you're saying *I want the last 10 characters of "Test"*. "Test" only has four characters, so trying to get the "last ten" will cause that error.

Comment: Yes .. But Iam getting my output as 123.000000. So that I take my substring as that. So now what can I do. Could you please give an other way to get the answer as 123.00

Comment: When you run this in a debugger, what is the value of "strtax" when it is first set (the line just before the substring)?

Comment: my value in strtax is 123.000000

Comment: Are you sure that's the value when the error is raised? Or is that the value the time it works, and some other time it raises the exception? Perhaps when you clear the function runs again, this time with a different result.

Comment: When I click the clear button strtax is getting 0 value. As you say thats why  iam getting that error. So What can i do for overcome that problem

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your end goal is to have the value formatted as money. If this is the case then you can use the handy Decimal.ToString("C"). There are many other formats that you may want instead, [see this link for more info on formatting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/26etazsy.aspx).